# Adding EditText input to ListView in seperate Activity

Tags: android, listview

> I am trying to send the String from EditText into the ListView (R.id.selectview) from my AddPLayer Class to my SelectPLayer Class. I can get the AddPlayer Activity to start SelectPLayer Activity using intent, but I can'not get the EditText input to populate the ListView. I hope this is a better explanation sorry and thank you.

```
//Addplayer class to add players using intent to separate activities
    public class AddPlayer extends Activity{

        //Declare buttons and edittext
        Button listButtonplayer1;
        Button listButtonplayer2;
        EditText playerIn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.playerinput);


            //Identify buttons and editext
            playerIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);

            listButtonplayer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
            listButtonplayer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //Using intent to send input to SelectPLayer Class
                    Intent i = new Intent(AddPlayer.this,SelectPlayer.class);

                    //Using string text_key to get and send string through intent
                    i.putExtra("text_key", playerIn.getText().toString());

                    //Start intent activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            //Second button I am trying to use for SelectPLayer2 activity only.
            listButtonplayer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton2);
            listButtonplayer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Using intent to send input to SelectPLayer2 Class
                    Intent in = new Intent(AddPlayer.this, SelectPlayer2.class);


                    in.putExtra("text", playerIn.getText().toString());

                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //Class to select player 1
    public class SelectPlayer extends Activity {



        //Public static array list with adapter to crete the array and reference for listview being sent by intent from AddPLayer class
        public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        public static ListView selectView;
        TextView title;
        Intent i;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.selectplayer);

            //Identify selectview ListView
            selectView = findViewById(R.id.selectview);
            selectView.setClickable(true);
            selectView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Using adapter for ListView menu
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            selectView.setAdapter(adapter);
            selectView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // finding the item which has been clicked by the user
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SelectPlayer.this, GameEmulator.class); //starting an intent to call GameEmulator Activity
                    intent.putExtra(GameEmulator.value, item);// Putting the value clicked by user in intent
                    startActivity(intent); // starting GameEmulator Activity
                    //Using intent to retrieve string from AddPlayer Activity
                    i = getIntent();
                    String data = i.getExtras().getString("text_key");
                    list.add(data);
                    changeList();
                }
            });
        }
        public  void changeList()
        {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: voted to close this question, because it is unknown within which Activity's context that code is being executed ...having a `SelectPlayer` and `SelectPlayer2` Activity also appears a little strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = getIntent();
String data = i.getExtras().getString("text_key");
list.add(data);
changeList();


public static void changeList()
{
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
selectView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

try this one.

Comment: I tried this but it did not seem to work, thank you. It seems when I try to retrieve string data using intent after the OnItemClick event in SelectPLayer, the String will be captured in the ListView. But if I do this my string returns null and my activity will not start on its own.